# How to start a cycle at frame 100 using modifiers?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I want to cycle an animation that doesn't start until frame 100. I want the animation range to loop from
100-130 for the remainder of the animation. Anytime I try to restrict the f-curve to frames 100 onward it only allows me to do it a single keyframe at a time. Obviously I wouldn't want to do this for an entire cycle piece by piece.

When I select multiple keyframes in the graph editor the f-curve options are no longer visible.

Comment: The cycles modifier has before and after settings. Please show your work as a Blender Screen Capture with keyframes.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the Cycles Modifier ... with the setting [Before Cycles] as -1.

Move the left most keyframe to 100.  Of course you can move multiple keyframes at once.